# In,ts.plot( gpars col=c("red","blue") returns only one colored plot) in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

i am not able to get 2 colors red and black in my ts.plot
    require(graphics)

```
ts.plot(window(CPI_ts,
           start=c(2012, 1),
           end=c(2019, 12)),
    window(IIP_ts,
          start=c(2012, 1),
          end=c(2019, 12)),

    gpars=list(xlab="Year",
               ylab="Index",
               col=c("red", "blue"),
               lwd=2))
  legend("topleft", bty="n", lty=c(1,1), col=c("red","blue"),
   legend=c(" IIP ", "CPI "))[CPI IIP index of india][1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the parameters to the function directly. This should work.

```
ts.plot(ts(rnorm(100), start = c(2001,1)),
        ts(rnorm(100), start = c(2001,1)), 
    col = c("red", "blue"), 
    xlab = "Year", 
    ylab = "Index", 
    lwd = 2)

legend("topleft", bty="n", lty=c(1,1), col=c("red","blue"),
       legend=c(" IIP ", "CPI "))
```

[image]